# Deep Link on IOS 15 doesn't redirect to the app - React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have set up deep links with react-navigation on my app and for ios 15 it doesn't redirect to the app.
My config :

- "react-native": "0.63.2",
- "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0-next.13"

Any idea ? I assume that the reason comes from the introduction of the deferred deep linking, but nothing on the react-navigation's doc.

Code of linking prop :

```js
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['https://*.mydomain.com'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        login: {
            path: "/loginPath"
        },
        signup: {
          path: "/signupPath"
        },
        home: {
          path: "/homePath"
        }
      }
    }
}

const MyAPP = () => (
  <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<FallbackComponent />}>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"home"}>
      <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login} />
      <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={Signup} />
      <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Home} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did it used to work earlier on? Have you set up the `linking` prop correctly? Could you post some code?

Comment: @Lucas Aubert can you share a code snippet of what you have tried and what not goes as expected,  developer in community will try to jump in and help.

Comment: I have put some codes... It works correctly on older versions of IOS and on Android. Does ios 15 needs a particular configuration ? Especially for deffered deep linking ?

Comment: Hi did you managed to make it work ? I have the same problem, deeplink won't work on iOS 15